# Why is array.length method one step behind the input in handleChange event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state, react-lifecycle

I'm trying to make an input filtered based list that only shows results when there are 10 or less objects, but the array.length is always lagging one step behind the input.

```
    const [countriesToShow, setCountriesToShow] = useState([])
    const [newSearch, setSearch] = useState('')
    const [showSearched, setShowShearched] = useState(true)
    const [notificationMessage, setNotificationMessage] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(countriesToShow.length)
    },[countriesToShow])
  
    const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
      setCountriesToShow(countries.filter(country =>
        country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())))
      setSearch(event.target.value)
      if (event.target.value.trim().length === 0) {
        setNotificationMessage(null)
        setShowShearched(false)
      }
      else if (countriesToShow.length <= 10) {
        setNotificationMessage(null)
        setShowShearched(true)
        console.log(countriesToShow.length)
      }
      else {
        setNotificationMessage('list too long')
        setShowShearched(false)
        console.log(countriesToShow.length)
      }
    }
```

I managed to get the console print the right length with the help of Effect Hook but I'm stumped about how to implement the same to the 'else if (countriesToShow.length <= 10)' as it still lags behind the input.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `handleSearchChange` and then call `setCountriesToShow` to udpate that state:

```
setCountriesToShow(
  countries.filter(country =>
    country
      .name
      .common
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
  )
)
```

You are triggering a re-render. The newly updated state value will only become available then, in the upcoming re-render, that's why it's lagging behind.

If you want to use that value below, you need to store it in a variable first:

```
const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
  const newCountriesToShow = countries.filter(country =>
    country
      .name
      .common
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
  )

  setCountriesToShow(newCountriesToShow)

  setSearch(event.target.value)

  if (event.target.value.trim().length === 0) {
    setNotificationMessage(null)
    setShowShearched(false)
  } else if (newCountriesToShow.length <= 10) {
    setNotificationMessage(null)
    setShowShearched(true)
  } else {
    setNotificationMessage('list too long')
    setShowShearched(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: I was typing my answer while you answered and since I went into a bit more detail on the other side of things (how it should be done) I posted anyways

Answer (score 0):

### The answer to your question

> Why is array.length method one step behind the input in handleChange event handler

This is because whenever you call `setCountriesToShow` you aren't updating the `countriesToShow` variable. This variable gets reinitialized on the next tick because the assignment to the result of the `useState` function is executed again when your component is run.

As an analogy you could consider this code:

```js
const _state = {
    value: 1
}

const useState = () => [_state.value, (newValue) => {_state.value = newValue}];

const myFunction = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState();

    setState(2);
    console.log(state); // Logs 1
}
```

this is basically how react works. So the local `state` variable never gets changed. When `myFunction` is rerun however the local `state` value will be reinitialized to the newest value

### How to fix it

You could of course make a temporary variable like `newCountriesToShow` and assign that to the new value and then call `setCountriesToShow(newCountriesToShow)` then inside of your function use `newCountriesToShow` this could work but is an anti pattern. You shouldn't do this unless you absolutely have to. See [Danziger's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76907141/10892722) for more details on this approach.

What React *wants* you to do here is to use derived values (`useMemo` or top level code). In general try to use as few `useState`s as possible (I'm not suggesting simply combining fields into an object when there is no other benefit but that is the exception)

```js
const [newSearch, setSearch] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(countriesToShow.length);
}, [countriesToShow]);

const countriesToShow = countries.filter((country) =>
  country.name.common
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(newSearch.toLowerCase())
);

const notificationMessage = countriesToShow.length > 10 ? "list too long" : null;
const showSearched = notificationMessage === null && newSearch.length !== 0;

const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
  setSearch(event.target.value);
};
```

Any code that you want to run when `notificationMessage` or `showSearched` changes should be in a `useEffect`

Comment: Oh I see. Big thanks for such a detailed answer.